# flush_cache_range() and flush_tlb_range() do not seem to work

Tags: linux, caching, memory-management, linux-kernel, tlb

Here is what I did:

1. A user space process uses `malloc()` to allocate memory on the heap and fills it with a specific pattern of characters and then spells out the address returned by the `malloc()`.
2. The process id and the address of the memory chunk are passed to a kernel module that looks like this:

   ```
   int init_module(void) {
   int res = 0;
   struct page *data_page;
   struct task_struct *task = NULL;
   struct vm_area_struct *next_vma;
   struct mm_struct *mm;

   task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
   if (pid != -1)
       target_process_id = pid;

   if (!task) {
       printk("Could not find the task struct for process id %d\n", pid);
       return 0;
   } else {
       printk("Found the task <%s>\n", task->comm);
   }

   mm = task->mm;

   if (!mm) {
       printk("Could not find the mmap struct for process id %d\n", pid);
       return 0;
   }

   next_vma = find_vma(mm, addr);

   down_read(&task->mm->mmap_sem);
   res = get_user_pages(task, task->mm, addr, 1, 1, 1, &data_page, NULL);

   if (res != 1) {
       printk(KERN_INFO "get_user_pages error\n");
       up_read(&task->mm->mmap_sem);
       return 0;
   } else {
       printk("Found vma struct and it starts at: %lu\n", next_vma->vm_start);
   }

   flush_cache_range(next_vma,next_vma->vm_start,next_vma->vm_end); 
   flush_tlb_range(next_vma,next_vma->vm_start,next_vma->vm_end); 

   up_read(&task->mm->mmap_sem);
   return 0;
   ```

   }
3. I added `printk()` statement to the `handle_mm_fault()` function in the Linux kernel to track page faults caused by `target_process_id` (3rd line of code after variable definitions above). Something like this:

   ```
   if (unlikely(current->pid == target_process_id))
          printk("Target process <%d> generated a page fault at address %lu\n", current->pid, address);
   ```

Now, what I noticed is that the last `printk()` statement does not catch anything.

*The function `init_module` is the initialization function for a kernel module. It is inserted into the running kernel using insmod...using the command `insmod module.ko pid=<processId> addr=<address>`*

Any idea what might going wrong?

Comment: How do you call init_module?

Comment: This is a kernel module. It is inserted into the running kernel using insmod...something like `insmod module.ko pid=<processId> addr=<address>`